# access to div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have created a webside, there I have a div element with the id "buttons". 
Below you see how i create buttons with the alphabet on them. Everything fine and it works. 
But now I have to get access to only one button/one letter of the 26 buttons.. so that I can change the opacity of one button. (i just can handle it that all of them get more transparent!)
maybe somebody can help me -thanks!

```
var buttons = function () {
    myButtons = document.getElementById("buttons");
    letters = document.createElement('ul');
    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        letters.id = 'alphabet';
            list = document.createElement('li'); 
            list.id = 'letter';
            list.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
        check();
            myButtons.appendChild(letters);
            letters.appendChild(list);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Create a codepen or fiddle so that we can see what's the problem is.

Comment: @hunzaboy — There's no need to resort to a third party site: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Can't you add an additional `id` to the alphabet buttons and then target the relevant `id` with CSS? Change `list.id = 'letter'` into `list.id = alphabet[i]` maybe

Comment: Your all ids of `li` is same `letter` and that is not valid

Answer (score 1):

You can set the id of your list elements with `list.id='letter' + i`.

Then you can access each button with `document.getElementById('letter<i>')` - for the first one `document.getElementById('letter0')` and so on.

You should move `letters.id = 'alphabet';` outside of your for-loop because you don't have to set the id in every loop.

Answer (score 1):

> I updated your codes, You can just see the example.

**Example:**

```js
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; /*Just Defined for this snipped test*/

var buttons = function (ID) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.id = 'alphabet';
    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            li = document.createElement('li'); 
            li.id = 'letter'+i;  /*id="letter0",id="letter1",...*/
            li.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
            /*check();*/
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    ID.appendChild(ul);
  }

 var myButtons = document.getElementById("buttons");
 buttons(myButtons);  /*Called the function and pass the Object for append*/
```

```html
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

**Generated HTML code from above snippet:**

```
<div id="buttons">
    <ul id="alphabet">
        <li id="letter0">A</li>
        <li id="letter1">B</li>
        <li id="letter2">C</li>
        .......................
        <li id="letter25">Z</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, you can use different `CSS` for every `ID's`. Or you can change `CSS` from `button()` function by updating your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may NOT use same ID to different elements (You had created more then one element and gave it same ID).

Here another method to solve the problem you had shown.  (without using "id" field), Just because you already have very good answers using the "id" property properly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test
        </title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            'use strict';
            var m_Buttons = [];
            function Init() {
                var myButtons = document.getElementById("buttons");
                var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']; //go on with letters yourself
                var ul = document.createElement('ul');
                var li = null;
                for (var i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++) {
                    li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
                    ul.appendChild(li);
                    m_Buttons.push (li);
                }
                myButtons.appendChild(ul);
            }

            function getButton(button_index) {
                m_Buttons[button_index].style.color = 'red';
                return Buttons[button_index];
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='Init();'>
        <div id='buttons'>
        </div>
        <button onclick='getButton(3);'> Click to get button 3 </button>
    </body>
</html>
```